# Can't Access the Albums of Currently Login Facebook User - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am having some trouble in my code. I gave the permission of "user_photos" in "loginwithreadpermission" but still not getting the users album. I also tried this "fbuserid/albums" but this is also not working for me. Please help me what I am doing wrong.

This is my Login Code:

```
@IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: AnyObject)
{


    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()
    facebookLogin.logOut()
    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email" , "user_photos"], fromViewController: nil) { (facebookResult, facebookError) in


        if facebookError != nil {
            print("Login Failed. Error: \(facebookError)")
        }
        else {
            if !(facebookResult.isCancelled)
            {

                let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
                if accessToken != nil
                {
                    token = accessToken

                    let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(accessToken)
                    print("1")
                    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential)
                    {
                        (user, error) in

                        if error != nil
                        {
                            print("Error Firebase: \(error)")
                        }
                        else
                        {


                            if self.userEmails.contains(user!.email!)
                            {
                                print("User Already Exist")

                                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(user?.uid, forKey: KEY_UID)
                                USER_UID = (user?.uid)!
                                print("id:\(USER_UID)")
                                LOGIN_FLAG = 1
                                FaceBookFlag = 1

                                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fbLogin", sender: nil)

                            }
                            else if user!.email != nil
                            {
                                print("Creating a User Data in FB")

                                var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me", parameters: ["fields":"email,first_name,age_range"]);
                                    request.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) in


                                        if error == nil
                                        {
                                            print("res: \(result)")
                                            if let dob = result.valueForKey("age_range") as? [String: AnyObject]
                                            {
                                                print("dd: \(dob["min"]!)")
                                                self.dateOfBirth = String(dob["min"]!)
                                                print("dob: \(dob)  , date: \(self.dateOfBirth)")
                                                print(" date: \(self.dateOfBirth!)")

                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            print("error:: \(error)")
                                        }




                                    let displayName = user?.displayName!.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
                                    let firstName = displayName![0]
                                    let lastName = displayName![1]
                                        print("url: \(user?.photoURL)")
                                    let profilePicUrl = user?.photoURL
                                    let picture = String(profilePicUrl!)
                                    let userEmail = user!.email!

                                    let _user = ["username": "\(firstName+lastName)","emailAddress": "\(userEmail)", "dateOfBirth": "\(self.dateOfBirth!)"]

                                    ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(_user)
                                    ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).child("images").setValue([picture])



                                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(user?.uid, forKey: KEY_UID)
                                    USER_UID = (user?.uid)!
                                    LOGIN_FLAG = 1
                                    FaceBookFlag = 1


                                    //Segue to reveal view controller
                                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fbLogin", sender: nil)
                                })
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And This is my Code where I am requesting to give me the albums of current user :

```
func getAlbums()
{

    //for sake of running i hardcoded the FBuserId.
    let fbid = "758111074330935"



     //169682503464671/photos
    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/\(fbid)/albums", parameters: ["fields":"photos,picture"] , HTTPMethod: "GET")




        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print(error)
            }
            else
            {
                print("rr:\(result)")
                let value = result.valueForKey("data")
                print("value:\(value) ... \(result["data"])")

                if let graphData = result.valueForKey("data") as? [AnyObject]
                {
                    print("array of Any")

                    for obj in graphData
                    {
                        print("id: \(obj.valueForKey("id")!)")
                        let id = String(obj.valueForKey("id")!)
                        self.albumsId.append(id)

                        //Also save the album link here to.
                    }
                }


            }
```

Comment: put "me/albums" instaed of "(fbid)/albums".

Comment: @ashmi123 i tried this to but didn't work

Comment: what error you get? ANd have u make the App on your FB account or other ?

Comment: Yes i have made all App settings which is required. First i logged in with the facebook account in which I have made app in developer account. But now i am logging in with another facebook account and its not giving me albums , just giving me empty dictionary : like this : { data = ( ); }

Comment: Yes so now you get your albums only right?

Comment: Yes i want only albums so I can fetch each albums ID.  Actually i am making an app in which user can login and select photos from his/her FB account albums. But I am not getting the albums

Comment: You got your FB account albums or not?

Comment: no. I didn't get my fb albums

Comment: Ok check with Graph API explore put there "me/albums" and send me the error print in the console.

Comment: Can u make chat over here

Comment: @ashmi123 please check these pictures:
User1: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztmijnr49ht1e2y/user1.JPG?dl=0] 
This user is the main facebook account from which I registered the app. 
User2: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/ld7d44dwpavvtue/User2.JPG?dl=0]
and this my personal facebook account. Now albums is empty because i haven't select the "user_photos" . Now what i want is that It should automatically check the "user_photos". 
And this is the result of User2: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/60xfnibcflw0v4r/result.JPG?dl=0]

Comment: Ok so you make the FB account on other User. See User1 : The FB registered app user. User2 : Your personal. Now you get User1 data its correct. If yoou use here your personal account or any other account it will not given you album . So for that you have to Submit your app on FB developer for review then any buddy can login and access there album.

Comment: Thank you soo Much @ashmi123 :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong set of **fields** for this type of request.
Check this doc to verify the fields that are available: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/album

In particular, I'm getting the following error (which is self-explained):

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: email,first_name.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "G0POfi9dWkb"
  }
}
```

Comment: i Just need the current user's album ID. So ignore the fields : email , first_name.